# App registrations, server and client, one for each cluster or reuse for all my clusters?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-rbac

I'm creating a couple of Kubernetes clusters using Azure AKS. I'll create a cluster for each environment. Dev, test and prod.

In the process I'm creating two ad apps. One for the server and one for the client.

Should I create a pair for each environment? Reuse both for all or just a client for each environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt make any difference strictly from perspective of AKS, but from ops\security perspective its better to create separate applications for each cluster.